# Should I leave my current job?

Tags: professionalism, management, work-environment, colleagues, mistakes

I make a minor mistake, something very minuscule, a few times a day like a typo/template error etc. However, every few weeks or so, I make a mistake where my boss may need to confront me after completing an audit. I’ve never been written up but I get mad at myself. Am I really terrible at my job? Or is this common amongst people? I’m new to the field, been working in the field for over a year. Should I look into something else. I feel that I try to be thorough or may overthink a process, some things slip through the cracks. I don’t think others get corrected to this extent, there are also a few people that I don’t care for. One in particular, I really do not talk at my job. Everyone shares of themselves to some degree, I really feel like they don’t know anything about me. People make remarks about my quietness, I’ve just had bad experiences at previous jobs, I really don’t fit in anywhere. With that at the back of my mind, I walked into this job with the mentality to truly stay to myself. Low and behold, shit still hit the fan.

Comment: I work in higher education, I mean I’ve seen other advisors (obviously myself) pulled aside. They forgot to follow up regarding a student and something fell through the cracks. Staying to myself doesn’t, what I’m saying is I have one enemy & I don’t talk to anyone at work. Which, is adding to my misery.

Comment: Well, one I’m asking if my issues are normal. And the other one I’m asking if I should just leave.

Comment: Hey there @DSG welcome to The Workplace. Please take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] so you get to know what sort of things is ok to ask here. Currently asking "Should I quit" is something off topic for this site (as Joe said, only you know if you should do it). Please review the links I shared and then try to [edit] your post into something we can answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it common to make mistakes often at work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/164086/is-it-common-to-make-mistakes-often-at-work)

Comment: I’m getting conflicting reviews compared to my other question so idk

Answer (score 1):

As noted, only you can answer that question. However, it reads like you have a lack of confidence with your current employer and possibly are suffering from a slight case of impostors syndrome.

The company and your boss hired you based on your qualifications so until they fire you or put you into a work development plan of some sorts, stop worrying about if you should leave. It's a gig and it pays the bills.

You can't control who you work with or how they interact with so you be you and let them be them. You say you don't care for some of your co-workers? Why is that? Their politics? Are they too loud? Are they the opposite of you? That's great! Are we not supposed to embrace the diversity and individuality of the workplace? Also, it doesn't matter! It's a job. If I had a nickel for every time I had to work with someone I didn't care for... I'd have 15 cents. Get over your personal bias and prejudices and focus on yourself. I have no doubt you are putting off a vibe that doesn't make you approachable. So how do you fix that?

You said you are new to the field. That's great. You get a honeymoon period to make small mistakes (unless you lied about your qualifications which is a whole other set of problems). You shouldn't hold yourself to perfection and is an unfortunate side affect of our work place society these days.

If you feel your perception is tied to the quality of your work then do something about it, don't wallow in despair.

You should always be learning. Who is the strongest peer in your work environment? Buy them a coffee or lunch and ask them what do they do to stay organized and on point and deliver quality work. Ask your boss what training materials you need to study to get better. Be attentive and take notes in all of your meetings. Find a mentor! Yes, it's a damn awkward conversation to have but it will go along way to giving you a sounding board for you dilemma. This forum can't replace that.

Most importantly, learn the business you are in. You were hired because it is thought you bring VALUE to the organization. You need to start working at figuring out what your employer sees in you.

Does all of this make you uncomfortable? Good. Get used to it. The common phrasing we use is "grow my career". Growing means putting yourself in position to be uncomfortable and learn from that experience.

You aren't the only one to suffer from anxiety like this. You control your destiny and it's no one else's fault if you feel you have to leave your current employer. However you will probably go on to a new employer and commit the same mistakes unless you stick it out now.

Good luck and I hope you stick with it. This day and age, it's good to have job.